# Parallelize/distribute subprocess call in dask each for one worker?

Tags: python, subprocess, dask

I have the following code that walks through each of project dirs, calls an external executable and writes results to out* files.

```
from dask_jobqueue import PBSCluster   
cluster = PBSCluster()
cluster.scale(jobs=3)  

from dask.distributed import Client
client = Client(cluster)
...

r_path='/path/to/project/folder'


def func():
    f = open('out', 'w') # In project, customized out_file naming based on different dir's
    (subprocess.call(["/path/to/executable/file"], stdout=f))

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("."):
    for name in dirs:
        os.chdir(r_path+'/'+str(name))
        func()
```

This code executes in a sequential manner but instead I would like to run it in parallel i.e. each subprocess call on one dask worker.

**Note:** I have same subprocess.call (same executable) for all the different dir's

I have tried this

```
def func():
   f = open('out', 'w') # In project, customized out_file naming based on different dir's
   func.file = (subprocess.call(["/path/to/executable/file"], stdout=f))


arg = [func.file]
workers = client.scheduler_info()['workers']
tasks = [client.submit(func, arg, workers=worker) for arg, worker in zip(args, workers)]
```

and also this ( probably not using dask to distribute/parallelize )

```
def func():
    f = open('out', 'w')
    with io.open(f, mode='wb') as out:
        p = subprocess.Popen(["/path/to/executable/file"], stdout=out, stderr=out)
        child_processes.append(p)

for cp in child_processes:
    cp.wait()
```

but couldn't parallelise/distribute the subprocess calls.

Could someone please help me in parallelising this subprocess calls for 1 worker each so that things can be executed faster.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Try having different file for different child process. Currently all child processes are waiting on writing to one file which might cause resource contention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Often, the first non-dask attempt shows the [easiest pattern to parallelise](https://tutorial.dask.org/01_dask.delayed.html#Exercise:-Parallelize-a-for-loop). However, I would caution against using global state with `os.chdir` - instead, refer to the output file by full path, and pass the working directory to the subprocess

```
r_path='/path/to/project/folder'

def func(path):
    f = open(os.path.join(path, 'out'), 'w')
    subprocess.call(["/path/to/executable/file"], stdout=f, cwd=path)

out = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("."):
    for name in dirs:
        path = r_path+'/'+str(name)
        out.append(dask.delayed(func)(path))

dask.compute(*out)
```

Comment: on following the code, I got this error: File "jr.py",  <module>
    client.compute(*out)
  File "//distributed/client.py", line 2695, in compute
    dsk = self.collections_to_dsk(variables, optimize_graph, **kwargs)
  File "//distributed/client.py", line 3783, in collections_to_dsk
    return collections_to_dsk(collections, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/k/base.py", line 209, in collections_to_dsk
    if optimize_graph:
  File "/delayed.py", line 545, in __bool__
    raise TypeError("Truth of Delayed objects is not supported")
TypeError: Truth of Delayed objects is not supported

Comment: following this thread https://github.com/dask/distributed/issues/3011, I tried client.compute(out). Thereafter, the python script ran successfully but executable file through subprocess.call didn't run at all. do you have any suggestions ? @mdurant

Comment: Not without an idea of what didn't run or an error message. You may want to put logging statements inside `func` to see exactly what it's trying to run, or compute one of the elements of `out` with the single-threaded scheduler `dask.compute(out[0], scheduler='sync')`, allowing you to debug.

Comment: for `client.computer(*out)`, the `print(out)` returns `[Delayed('func-7df87783-4dd0-4c27-b5b3-e5a7b4d814ee'), Delayed('func-997bc74f-78ef-4665-b89f-b30fd535700c'), Delayed('func-1e9f26d2-7a45-422d-a29e-078288d9ebdc')]` along with **TypeError:** Truth of Delayed objects is not supported

Comment: for `client.computer(out)`, the code runs successfully without computing the subprocess.call. The `print(out)` returns the list `[Delayed('func-7995379c-4080-4195-8436-f10b209ad4cb'), Delayed('func-411161ba-6614-4b23-ba79-7634f81bfd62'), Delayed('func-ae13b364-f7c6-4988-ab0a-3de2f7c2eba9')]`

Comment: adding the line `dask.compute(out[0], scheduler='sync')` after `client.compute(out)` actually computes the first dir in the list and writes results into **out** file in the root dir. Could you please suggest the changes that I have to make ?@mdurant